# How Can I Set the width and height of an image in XAML?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to set the height and width of an image in Xaml, I have tried with

```
<Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

But At the runtime stops and say that this properties are readonly.

Comment: <Image WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100"/> This is the correct way You can give like this in Xamarin.Android but not in Forms.

Answer (score 4):

```
<Image WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100"/>
```

Comment: Yup! `Width` and `Height` should really be read-only because they tell the actual width and height of the control after it has been rendered on the screen. To set the width and height, you have to use `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` and Xamarin.Forms will try to abide by the request, but because certain screens won't be able to display the content at the requested width and height, Xamarin.Forms adjusts the width/height accordingly to fit the screen.